# Which methods internally call GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, clr, gethashcode

I am aware of the importance to override `GetHashCode` when we override `Equals` method. I assume `Equals` internally calls `GetHashCode`.

What are the other methods that might be internally using `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Implementations of `Equals()` don't normally call `GetHashCode()`, but any hashing container will call it for the elements of its collection.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a nice blog about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: My apologies, when I call a Overriden `Equals` method. `GetHashCode`is internally called without explicit mention in the Overriden `Equals` method.

Hence wanted to know what all cases triggers the call of 'GetHashCode'

Comment: This is a question you should never ask.  What other code runs in a program that *might* use it is unknowable.

Comment: If we override `GetHashCode` wont it be good to know where all it will used? From Brian's comment below it might will be used extensively in LINQ queries... I was expecting such answer :)

Comment: Step 1: Download the .NET BCL source code, available on the Microsoft website, and string-search for GetHashCode. Step 2: . Step 3: Profit!

Answer (score 4):

`Equals` doesn't internally call `GetHashCode`.
`GetHashCode` is used by many classes as a means to improve performance: If the hash codes of two instances differ, the instances are not equal *by definition* so the call to `Equals` can be skipped.
Only if the hash codes are the same it needs to call `Equals`, because multiple instances can have the same hash code, even if they are different.

Concrete examples of classes that work like this:

- [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)
- [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

> I assume Equals internally calls GetHashCode.

That would be pretty unusual actually. `GetHashCode` is used mainly by dictionaries and other hash-set based implementations; so: `Hashtable`, `Dictionary<,>`, `HashSet<>`, and a range of other things. Basically, `GetHashCode` serves two purposes:

- getting a number which *loosely* represents the value, and which can be used, for example, for distributing a set of keys over a range of buckets via modulo, or any other numeric categorisation
- proving non-equality (but never proving equality)

See also: [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden?rq=1)

Comment: As an addition to Marc's examples, it's worth noting that Linq makes frequent use of GetHashCode.